# How to transfer items from a ListBox to a collection VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, collections, listbox

In one of my forms I have got a ListBox (formListBox) which contains a list of string items. What I would like to do is transfer all the items in the list box into a collection. So far I've tried the following without success:

```
            Dim newItems As New ListBox.ObjectCollection(formListBox)
            For Each item As String In newItems
                myArrayList.addNewItem(item)
            Next
```

After this is executed the number of items in the arraylist comes back as 0. I have a feeling I am misunderstanding the "ListBox.ObjectCollection(formListBox)" part - the impression I got from this is that it returns a collection from the ListBox but the results I get suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim arr1()
ReDim arr1(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1)
ListBox1.Items.CopyTo(arr1, 0)
```

OR

```
Dim ArrayItems() As String     

'//ADD ITEMS INTO ARRAY 
'//FIRST FIND HOW MANY ITEMS IN LISTBOX AND REDIM THE ARRAT FOR SIZE 
ReDim ArrayItems(List1.ListCount) 

'//NOW ADD ITEMS 
For i = 1 To List1.ListCount 
   List1.ListIndex = i - 1 
   ArrayItems(i) = List1.Text 
Next i
```

OR

Using LINQ

```
(From item As Object In yourListBox.ObjectCollection Select item.ToString()).ToArray()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Tried the first one and it worked